# Invalid syntax print method

Tags: python, syntax

It's error. I don't know how to

```
if (os == "Linux"):
    print("#!/bin/sh")
    print("screen java -Xincgc -Xmx"+ram+" -jar "+name+".jar"
if (os == "Windows"):
    print("@echo off")
    print("SET BINDIR=%~dp0")
    print("CD /D "+'"'+"/%BINDIR%/"+'"')
    print("java "+"-Xmx"+ram+" -Xms"+ram+" -jar "+name+".jar")
```

Its's invalid syntax

```
  File "MC0_3.py", line 32
    if (os == "Windows"):
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: closing ( is missing in your code

Comment: This appears to be off-topic as the problem was caused by a simple typographical error. This is unlikely to help future visitors and can often be avoided by trying to reproduce the problem with the shortest code possible.

Answer (score 2):

Following line is missing closing parenthesis (`)`)

```
print("screen java -Xincgc -Xmx"+ram+" -jar "+name+".jar")
                                                         ^
```

BTW, you can use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) or [`%`-operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) instead of concatenating strings using `+` operator:

```
print("screen java -Xincgc -Xmx{} -jar {}.jar".format(ram, name))

print("screen java -Xincgc -Xmx%s -jar %s.jar" % (ram, name))
```